# How do I get this label to point to the leftmost bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I tried the following code but instead of showing the label in middle, I want to point it to leftmost (you can see my picture under). Thanks for the help!

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am, cyl) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = am, y = mpg, group = cyl, fill = cyl, label = mpg)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_label_repel(data = mtcars %>% filter(am == 0, 
                                            cyl == 4) %>% 
                     slice(1),
                   nudge_x = 0.2,
                   nudge_y = 0.3,
                   aes(fill = NULL))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution will work generally, for any combination of labels.

First, it seems as if the `am` variable is a binary factor, so I code it as a factor so the x axis is a little cleaner. In your case, you are looking for `position_dodge(width = 1)` for your labels, which automatically lines the labels up on top of the corresponding bars. The way I thought was best for subsetting to only the one label you want us ti define a column `mpg_lab` which is NA for all the labels you don't want. If you change the conditions in the last `mutate` row you can isolate different labels, or delete that row altogether for all the labels.

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(am = factor(am)) %>% 
  group_by(am, cyl) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  mutate(mpg_lab = ifelse(am == 0 & cyl == 4, mpg, NA))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = am, y = mpg, group = cyl, fill = cyl)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  geom_label_repel(data = df, 
             aes(label = mpg_lab, fill = NULL), position = position_dodge(width = 1), point.padding = NA, ylim = max(df$mpg_lab, na.rm = T) * 1.02)
```

[image]

A couple of optional things I added was turning off `point.padding` in `geom_label_repel` to keep the labels from randomly moving around side-to-side. I also bumped the label up so you can see the arrow by using the `ylim` argument in there. You can play around with those options if you want something different.

Comment: Thanks astrofunkswag for this generalized answer it works great!

Answer (score 1):

On way is to use `geom_text` instead. You don't get the white background around the label, but you can position it exactly:

```
mtcars %>% 
 group_by(am, cyl) %>% 
 slice(1) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = am, y = mpg, group = cyl, fill = cyl, label = mpg)) + 
 geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
 geom_text(data = mtcars %>% filter(am == 0,cyl == 4) %>% slice(1),
           nudge_x = -0.3,
           nudge_y = 0.7,
           aes(fill = NULL))
```

## Edit:

As pointed out, `geom_label` will make the white background, which is a much nicer option :P

Comment: You can simply use `geom_label` instead of `geom_text`.

Comment: This also just nudges the label around until it is over the correct bar. This is a fine workaround if it's a one-off plot but wouldn't work if you applied the code to another context, say if you changed `cyl` to 8 in the label code

Comment: Hi Rab thanks for the answer! and @Axeman for the improvement. it works nice but I do want to keep the arrow as in geom_label_repel, any suggestions? much appreciated